# What will happen if Eve gets the alphabets in BB84 protocol?

Tags: quantum-information

In BB84 protocol, Alice and Bob will exchange the alphabets (or the operators to perform mearsurements) over a classical channel. What will happen if Eve, the eavesdropper, intercepts the qubits and the alphabets?

In my opinion,  Eve can know the "correct" alphabets and perform mearsurements without being found, since the qubits that remains (in Alice and Bob's key) are just eigenstates of these operators.

Answer (score 2):

Alice must wait until Bob receives the qubits to send the classical information. If Bob has received some qubits, it is guaranteed that Alice, Bob, and Eve cannot possibly all have the same qubits, since Eve does not know in which basis to measure the qubits that Alice sent, and she can't send the same qubits to Bob without measuring them (by the no-cloning theorem). The best Eve can do is guess, and if she guesses wrong she is detected with overwhelmingly high probability.

If the three do not have the same qubits, either Alice and Bob have the same qubits and Eve does not (so Eve cannot learn the key) or Alice and Bob do *not* have the same qubits, and abort the protocol when their chosen qubits do not match.

Like any key exchange method, it can be subverted if used without authentication by executing a man-in-the-middle attack. This is not a failure of BB84, but a general property of key exchanges. Key exchange methods are essentially methods for turning authentication into encryption- without authentication, Eve can simply negotiate two separate exchanges with Alice and Bob.

Comment: Still confused. Why can't Eve attack them and get the information *after* Alice and Bob exchanged the key?

Comment: @Stone-Zeng At that point, she can't get the qubits, which contain the key. The classical information is worthless without the qubits.